# Hard Disk Partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

While installing Ubuntu I went with default partitioning without knowing what it actually was. I have a 500GB hard drive, and after installation, all of it is converged to a single partition, on which the OS got installed. Now I want to make partitions and have already searched for the solution, but couldn't come up with the one. Please guide, how can I make multiple partitions from this single partition?

```
Partition: /dev/sda2
Name: *Nothing appears here*
File System: ext4
Mount Point: /
Size: 457.40 GiB
Used: 14.04 GiB
Unused: 443.36 GiB
Flags: *Nothing appears here*
```

THIS IS THE DRIVE THAT I WANT TO SHRINK FURTHER INTO NEW VOLUMES.

Apart from this drive, there are following partitions visible (as in gparted):

```
Partition: /dev/sda1
Name: EFI System Partition
File System: fat32
Mount Point: /boot/efi
Size: 512.00 MiB
Used: 4.60 MiB
Unused: 507.40 MiB
Flags: boot, esp
```

and

```
Partition: /dev/sda3
Name: *Nothing appears here*
File System: linux-swap
Mount Point: *Nothing appears here*
Size: 7.86 GiB
Used: 0.00 B
Unused: 7.86 GiB
Flags: *Nothing appears here*
```

I also have 1.02 MiB unallocated space appearing as a fourth partition

Comment: I would start over again following this http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Why would you want to have more than one partition? You always run the risk of having to repartition, as your initial selection might be wrong (one partition running out of space, another one being too big).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot Ubuntu from Live USB or DVD, and use 'gparted' to shrink sda2 and create new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu, click "Use custom partition layout" and create a table based on the sizes youd like for each partition.

Comment: Thank you, but is there no alternate than reinstalling the OS?

Comment: This was my preferred solution when I was just starting out. The other option requires booting into a Live session from another computer using a program called gparted. You'll learn to do this eventually; it's not that hard really but if you don't mind wiping the disk you're better off just trying again.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS seems to be the most suitable solution at the moment. Thanks!